# Regex, I just don't get it right

Tags: regex

I just don't get my Regex right:

I have the following template:

```
<!-- Defines the template for the tabs. -->
{{TMPL:Import=../../../../Data/Templates/Ribbon/tabs.tmpl; Name=Tabs}}
<div class="tabs">
    <ul role="tablist">
        {{BOS:Sequence}}
        <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
            <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
        </li>
        {{EOS:Sequence}}
    </ul>
</div>
{{Render:Tabs}}
```

I would like to find everything between `{{}}` except the tags that begins with `{{BOS`, `{{EOS`, `{{TMPL`, `{{Render`

Here are a couple approaches:

**Attempt 1:**

```
({{).*(}})
```

This selects everything between `{{ }}` tags, which is not good.

**Attempt 2:**

```
({{)[^TMPL][^BOS][^EOS][^Render].*(}})
```

This will make that `{{TabType}}` and `{{TabFile}}` are not selected anymore and I just don't know why.

With some other regex, I get that `{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}` is selected as one match.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this, I really need a regex Guru :-)

Comment: What language are you doing this in?  Different regex implementations will lead to different answers.

Comment: I'm writing javascript regex :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead based regex like this:

```
{{(?!TMPL|[BE]OS|Render).*?}}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qC4gV8/3)

Comment: That's because `sed` is weird with regex.  
try `sed -r` and see if that helps

Comment: Of course sed doesn't support lookahead but question didn't say anything about `sed`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I'll accept is when I can (couple of minutes waiting). What is sed -r?

Comment: I don't think `sed -r` has any relation with this answer and even `sed -r` doesn't support lookahead.

Comment: Yea I doubt it. `sed` is a command-line thing, not something you need to worry about here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following regex to get the content between braces:

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

**[Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ9eZ7/1)**

If you want to exclude the content from the comment you posted you can use a regex technique to exclude what you don't want and keep what you want at the end of the regex:

```
\{\{BOS:Sequence\}\}|\{\{EOS:Sequence\}\}|\{\{TMPL:Import.*?\}\}|\{\{Render:Tabs\}\}|\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ9eZ7/2)**

By the way, if you want to have a shortcut for above regex you can use:

```
\{\{(?:BOS|EOS):Sequence\}\}|\{\{TMPL:Import.*?\}\}|\{\{Render:Tabs\}\}|\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

This is a very useful technique for pattern exclusion that I glad to learn it from Anubhava and zx81 (they rock using regex pattern). For this regex technique you can find the content you need using capturing groups (check the green highlights on the screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: But now everything is found. I don't want the {{BOS:Sequence}}, {{EOS:Sequence}}, {{TMPL:Import=../../../../Data/Templates/Ribbon/tabs.tmpl; Name=Tabs}} and {{Render:Tabs}} I just want the data between {{ }} that contains literals without other signs in it.

Comment: @Complexity I've updated the answer to show how to get te content between braces and and also skipping what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[^TMPL]` and the like won't work because these are character *classes*.  You could use a negative lookahead, though (or even lookbehind depending upon the regex library you are using).

```
\{\{(?!BOS:)(?!EOS:)(?!Render:)(?!TMPL:)(.*?)\}\}
```

Still I get the feeling that you want the `BOS`, `EOS`, etc. to just be strings in the template with `{{` and other values to be interpolated.  If you are using handlebars or something, you can have strings interpolated:

```
{{'{{BOS:Sequence}}'}}
```